# Jface : is there any way to customize field decoration?

Tags: jface

I think the default gif image looks bad, so I want to swap those images!

I know that I can hack the jface jar file.but I wonder is there any public API to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.FieldDecoration#setImage(Image)

public void setImage(Image image)
Set the image shown in the decoration, or null if no image is specified. It is up to the caller to update any decorated fields that are showing the description in order to display the new image.
Parameters:
image - the image shown in the decoration. A value of null signifies a blank decoration.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ffieldassist%2FFieldDecoration.html